# get argument from tuple for passing

Tags: python

Is there any short cut to this?

I get list of tuple like this from a function .

```
lot = [('foo', 'bar', 'tar'), ('foo1', 'bar1', 'tar1')]
```

I am passing the same in another funciton like this.

```
for args in lot:
    (arg1, arg2, arg3) = args
    var = somefunction(arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

Comment: `somefunction(*args)`

Comment: Thanks. Works as expected. Yes it is duplicate. I was using keyword uncompressing which was not indexing this answer.

Comment: Depending on what you want to achieve, also consider `itertools.starmap(some_function, lot)`.